# How to get the URL to download a Homebrew Bottle?

Tags: macos, homebrew

How can I figure out the URL to download the bottle for a given package on Homebrew?

Consider the package `wget`. In the past, I could download the [`wget` Homebrew bottle](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/wget) at the following URL:

- https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/wget-1.20.3_2.catalina.bottle.tar.gz

Unfortunately, that link no longer works.

How can I determine the URL to download a Homebrew bottle?

Comment: Homebrew hasn't used bintray for a very long time.  What problem are you trying to solve by downloading bottles directly?

Comment: I'm trying to have a local copies of the bottles that I need for offline install. How do I get their URL?

Comment: See also https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/35172#discussioncomment-8738476

Comment: See also [How to download a file from GitHub Container Registry (CLI command, GitHub Packages)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78164818/how-to-download-a-file-from-github-container-registry-cli-command-github-packa)